# Go (golang) - do method pointers always increment per source definition?

Tags: pointers, go

When methods are defined in Go, does the pointer *always* increment in the exact order in which they are defined in source - or is it possible that lower pointer space could be re-allocated?

For example - is `methods` now in the guaranteed order of A, Z, D, B regardless of go version or arch?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sort"
)

type t struct{}

func (a *t) A() {}
func (a *t) Z() {}
func (a *t) D() {}
func (a *t) B() {}

type addr struct {
    Addr   uintptr
    Method string
}

type addrList []addr

func (a addrList) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}

func (a addrList) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i].Addr < a[j].Addr
}
func (a addrList) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}

func main() {

    methods := addrList{}
    fooType := reflect.TypeOf(&t{})

    for i := 0; i < fooType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := fooType.Method(i)
        methods = append(methods, addr{method.Func.Pointer(), method.Name})
    }

    sort.Sort(methods)
    fmt.Println(methods)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> This is a reference manual for the Go programming language.

The order is not defined in the Go language specification therefore the order is undefined. It's implementation dependent.